# How JVM creates object of abstract class?

Tags: java, jvm

I could not get how JVM gives output 10. We cannot create object of abstract class, then how JMV internally manages object creation of abstract class.

```
abstract class A {
    int a = 10;
}

class B extends A {
    int a = 20; 
}

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        A obj = new B();
        System.out.println(obj.a); // prints 10
        System.out.println(((B)obj).a); // prints 20
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't create an instance of the abstract class A. It creates an instance of the concrete class B.

However, since the variable `obj` used to hold the reference to the object is of type A, and since instance members (unlike methods) can't be overridden, `obj.a` returns the `a` variable of class `A`.

You can convince yourself that an instance of B was created by adding to your code :

```
public class Sample 
{ 
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        A obj = new B(); 
        System.out.println(obj.a); // prints 10
        System.out.println(((B)obj).a); // prints 20
    } 
}
```

Comment: @GyroGearless The code in the question was edited after I posted my answer.